# Physical Mailing Address

Tags: email, email-template, images

We are trying to send a test email for a template we have created but we keep getting this error message (see attached image). Can you help, we do not have coding experience and are new to the software so we are struggling to work out what we need to do.

Also when we are on the test and preview page the images which we have added to the email are not showing and again we can't see why this would be.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: can u be specific what kind of error you are getting???

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to be more specific, and include your error message (in text, not as an image if possible)? Additionally, are you using the Marketing Cloud? If so, adding that as a tag would help the visibility of your question.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are saying here,as i dont see an attachment.
but from your description it sounds like two hints:
- setup > email administration>deliverability > All Email !

pictures added to your template needs to be stored in salesforce and public available

any other, please edit your question and provide more detail